# Roscpp Publisher not publishing all messages

Tags: ros, roscpp, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a node that is publishing a lot of messages (approximately 135 per second). It should be publishing more. Every time I publish a message, I print out a debug line, and the number of debug lines exceeds the number of messages received. The messages received have sequential header.seq numbers.

This is using a roscpp node on one computer. The publishing takes place in a callback.

Why would some of the messages not get published?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34619/roscpp-publisher-not-publishing-all-messages/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2012-05-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-05-23**:
If there are sequential numbers my guess would be that some queue in the publisher overruns. Do you see any messages when you switch the loggers to DEBUG?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-05-23**:
How big are your buffers (subscriber and publisher)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both of you are right. I only had the queue size set to one, which is seemingly obvious.

In my defense, I checked the constructor for the roscpp Publisher and didn't see a queue size parameter. It's in advertise. D'oh.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2012-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1